# "The Single Sign-On Gateway Url is invalid" error when making API calls

Tags: api, single-sign-on, simple-salesforce, facebook, federated-authentication

I'm testing API calls to Salesforce via Connected Apps in an environment where SSO is enforced via Permission sets. For the SSO I'm federating using Facebook.
The communication works fine without SSO (credentials validated), but when I attach the permission set to the service user associated to the connection app, I get the following error messages:

- If "Delegated Gateway URL" is empty: Error "The Single Sign-On Gateway Url is invalid"
- If "Delegated Gateway URL" has another value: "Your company's authentication service is down"
  The connection via the portal works just as expected (it connects fine through facebook).
  Should I add some value on "Delegated Gateway URL" for the federation with Facebook? Or maybe it's a different configuration issue?

ps - I've tried to connected using both simple_salesforce and requests (I'm using Python), same issue in both cases. I've also tested enabling "Make Federation ID case-insensitive" as suggested in other posts in this forum but it didn't work in my case.